# Sort a list of textbox objects

Tags: c#, list, sorting, textbox

I want to scan in some serial numbers to read only textboxes. I created a list of the text boxes and I cant figure out how to sort them by the textbox name:

```
// This gets all the textboxnames ands makes an array of names and textboxes
foreach (Control groupbox in this.Controls)
{
    if (groupbox is GroupBox)
    {
        foreach (Control textbox in groupbox.Controls)
        {
            if (textbox is TextBox)
            {
                theTextBoxesList.Add((TextBox)textbox);
                TextBoxNames.Add(textbox.Name);

            }
        }
    }
}
TextBoxNames.Sort();

theTextBoxesList.Sort?????
```

Answer (score 2):

I think to sort TextBox List, LINQ Query may help you. Use OrderBy to sort TextBox in Ascending order, or Use OrderByDescending to sort TextBox in Descending order.

Ascending sorting:

```
theTextBoxesList = theTextBoxesList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Descending sorting:

```
theTextBoxesList = theTextBoxesList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Does this Help?

For more information on Sorting Data visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx

Comment: YES!! it worked, I really need to study more about the LINQ query and lamdba thanks you guys

Comment: @carlosap visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746.aspx, you will find download link for C# LINQ samples.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
theTextBoxesList = theTextBoxesList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).toList();
```

It should work.

Comment: This answer is little more than a single line of code with no explanation - which doesn't make it a particularly **good** answer. Try putting a little bit of commentary in so that the OP understands what is going on.

Comment: thanks dbaseman you are awesome, but it seems that I might be missing something else, I tried it and it didnt sort it. could it be that the name is burrien under the control, the groupbox and the component layer?

Comment: thanks this line : theTextBoxesList = theTextBoxesList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).toList();
 for some reason worked now

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the comparison, as `TextBox` isn't a primitive type:

```
theTextBoxesList.Sort(new Comparison<TextBox>(
    (tb1, tb2) => { return tb1.Name.CompareTo(tb1.Name); }
));
```

Comment: could i compare the name of the TextBox with with my textboxNames list?

Comment: @carlosap I suppose you could, but why would you want to?  It's the same info, just harder because it's in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

```
theTextBoxesList.Sort( (a,b) => String.Compare(a.S,b.S) );
```